# How to customize Spring webflux error page

Tags: spring-webflux

When I try to create a demo project on spring initializr and choose spring-boot-starter-webflux I can't for my life customize my error pages. I have tried putting the templates under /resources/public/error, /resources/templates/error (I am using Thymeleaf), defining a custom ErrorController to no avail. Each time I want to throw a 404 page for example the application throws the WhiteLabel page. BUT when I change the dependency to spring-boot-starter-web it picks my templates right away.

Is there some other way of declaring the error pages or this is just a bug (currently using Spring Boot 2.1.0.RC1 but same thing happens with 2.1.0.M4)?

My dependencies are as follows:

```
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to change the Spring Boot version to 2.0.5.RELEASE as 2.0.6.RELEASE was exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: This isn’t solved. This is probably a bug. Could you raise an issue on the Spring Boot tracker?

Comment: Thanks, I just have. 2.1.0 has just released and the behaviour is the same.